can we use dynamic variable in DBT models
The requirement is to use a dynamic variable in posthook, I just don't know if its possible in dbt model
example :


have you tried your approach? if so, how did it go? did you see any errors?

yes it did not work, I think set only accepts static values

why did not use the max_time_column query directly in the post_hook?

it is for an incremental approach, we need to store the max_time_column before running the model as we have to use that again to handle some delete logic after the completion of model(post hook), because once the model is run, the max_time_column will change to some other time

Move your set variable to top.
Then append the variable name in posthook using ~
e.g.
{% set var1 = 1 %}

{{
    config(
        ...,
        post_hook = "update table set column = 0 where col1 = " ~ var1
    )
}}


var1 is not static and not direct, we are getting that by running a query

It's still same corect instead of 1, put query to assign value to variable
